# Transform a table with duplicate unique id's with different column values onto a single row

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I am trying to transform the current format I have my data in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6rqC.png) into the format of image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb5lO.png). As you can see the data is currently split over two rows per one cust_id for each code they have but I want it on a single line. The open and replied for a given code is mutually exclusive for 1's i.e. custx for code A does not have matching assigned values of 1 & 1 for open and replied but can have a 0 & 0, 1 & 0 or 0 & 1.  I am using Oracle SQL Developer 19.2.1. Thank you in advance

Current SQL data format

[image]

Desired SQL data format

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de9a4169e081620a80787bf75d19736e).

```
select
    cust_key,
    min(case when code = 'A' then open end) as A_open,
    min(case when code = 'B' then open end) as B_open,
    min(case when code = 'A' then replied end) as A_replied,
    min(case when code = 'B' then replied end) as B_replied
from yourTable
group by
    cust_key
```

Output:

```
|cust_key    A_open  B_open  A_replied  B_replied |
---------------------------------------------------
| cust1          0       0          1         0   |
| cust2          0       0          1         1   |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'PIVOT' like below.

```sql
with xxx as (
select 'cust1' custkey,'A' code, 0 opened,1 replied from dual
union all
select 'cust1' custkey,'B' code, 0 opened,0 replied from dual
union all
select 'cust2' custkey,'A' code, 0 opened,1 replied from dual
union all
select 'cust2' custkey,'B' code, 0 opened,1 replied from dual
)
    SELECT  *  FROM 
(
    select xxx.* from XXX
)
PIVOT
(
    sum(opened) as OPENED,sum(replied) REPLIED  FOR (CODE) IN ('A' AS A,'B' AS B) 
)
    group by custkey,a_opened,a_REPLIED,b_opened,b_REPLIED
```

Comment: Thanks for the code mustafa this is a nice solution